# Linq to Objects to query LLBLGen projection

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects, llblgenpro

I'm trying to use the recommended LLBLGen syntax to query a projection (http://www.llblgen.com/documentation/3.5/LLBLGen%20Pro%20RTF/Using%20the%20generated%20code/Adapter/gencode_usingentityview_adapter.htm#projections)

```
IEntityView2 view = table.DefaultView;
List<A1AllocationHelp1TableDTO> something = 
    (from c in view
     select new A1AllocationHelp1TableDTO
     {
         RecordStatus = c.RecordStatus,
         UniqueIdent = c.UniqueIdent
     }).ToList();
```

But I'm getting this error on 'select':

```
The type arguments for method 'IEnumerable<TResult>
System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource>,
Func<TSource, TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the query.
```

Funny is that the same works just fine in VB.Net

```
Dim view As IEntityView2 = table.DefaultView
Dim something As List(Of A1AllocationHelp1TableDTO) = _
    (From c In view
     Select New A1AllocationHelp1TableDTO With _
          {
              .RecordStatus = c.RecordStatus, _
              .UniqueIdent = c.UniqueIdent
          }).ToList()
```

I'm using VS2010, .NET 4 and LLBLGen 2.6.
Can't figure out how to fix this can anyone give me a hand?

Thanks

Edit:

IEntityView2 is generated by LLBLGen and this is its definition

```
public interface IEntityView2 : IEnumerable
{
    bool AllowEdit { get; set; }
    bool AllowNew { get; set; }
    bool AllowRemove { get; set; }
    int Count { get; }
    PostCollectionChangeAction DataChangeAction { get; set; }
    IPredicate Filter { get; set; }
    IEntityCollection2 RelatedCollection { get; }
    ISortExpression Sorter { get; set; }
    IEntity2 this[int index] { get; }
    event ListChangedEventHandler ListChanged;
    bool Contains(IEntity2 value);
    void CreateProjection(List<IEntityPropertyProjector> propertyProjectors, DataTable destination);
    void CreateProjection(List<IEntityPropertyProjector> propertyProjectors, IEntityCollection2 destination);
    void CreateProjection(List<IEntityPropertyProjector> propertyProjectors, IEntityDataProjector projector);
    void CreateProjection(List<IEntityPropertyProjector> propertyProjectors, DataTable destination, bool allowDuplicates);
    void CreateProjection(List<IEntityPropertyProjector> propertyProjectors, IEntityCollection2 destination, bool allowDuplicates);
    void CreateProjection(List<IEntityPropertyProjector> propertyProjectors, IEntityDataProjector projector, bool allowDuplicates);
    void CreateProjection(List<IEntityPropertyProjector> propertyProjectors, DataTable destination, bool allowDuplicates, IPredicate filter);
    void CreateProjection(List<IEntityPropertyProjector> propertyProjectors, IEntityCollection2 destination, bool allowDuplicates, IPredicate filter);
    void CreateProjection(List<IEntityPropertyProjector> propertyProjectors, IEntityDataProjector projector, bool allowDuplicates, IPredicate filter);
    int IndexOf(IEntity2 value);
    IEntityCollection2 ToEntityCollection();
    IEntityCollection2 ToEntityCollection(int startIndex);
}
```

Comment: Please show the definition of `IEntityView2`.

Comment: I've edited to add the definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IEntityView2` inherits the non-generic interface `IEnumerable`. The `Select` method however needs the generic version. That's why you are getting the error.

Assuming that the properties you want to access are defined on `IEntity2`, the following will work:

```
view.Cast<IEntity2>()
    .Select(c => new A1AllocationHelp1TableDTO
           {
               RecordStatus = c.RecordStatus,
               UniqueIdent = c.UniqueIdent
           })
    .ToList();
```

It works in VB.NET because it uses late binding. You can easily see this on the following sample:

```
Dim view As IEntityView2 = table.DefaultView
Dim something As List(Of A1AllocationHelp1TableDTO) = _
(From c In view
 Select New A1AllocationHelp1TableDTO With _
      {
          .RecordStatus = c.IDontExist _
      }).ToList()
```

I am using a property that doesn't exist (`IDontExist`). This code will still compile but throw an exception at runtime:

```
MissingMemberException: Public member 'IDontExist' on type 'IEntity2' not found.
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Symbols.Container.GetMembers(String& MemberName, Boolean ReportErrors)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.ObjectLateGet(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

Comment: The cast is actually to view.Cast<A1AllocationHelp1TableDTO>().Select(c =>... but that's exactly what I needed

Comment: @kooshka: But why the select at all? If the items in the `view` already are of the target object, all you need to do is this: `view.Cast<A1AllocationHelp1TableDTO>().ToList();`. No need for creating new objects.

Comment: My bad. I mean Cast<A1AllocationHelp1Entity>. view holds instances of A1AllocationHelp1Entity which is defined at runtime only, because this is in a WCF I then need to return a static defined DTO

Answer (score 0):

.DefaultView returns a typed view, which implements IEntityView2, but you shouldn't cast it to IEntityView2, as you then lose the generic type. So you should have done:

```
List<A1AllocationHelp1TableDTO> something = 
    (from c in table.DefaultView
     select new A1AllocationHelp1TableDTO
     {
         RecordStatus = c.RecordStatus,
         UniqueIdent = c.UniqueIdent
     }).ToList();
```

This way, the compiler knows the generic type of the view.

Comment: Thanks Frans, but that doesn't work either, I still get the same error. table is of type IEntityCollection2